# How to reposition & align my two elements?

Tags: html, css, position, alignment

hope you could help me out, have two questions:

1. How do i simply reposition my main image of sunset 110px from the top.
2. and also how do i get my logo to flow exactly between the image and left-side.

if you know one or both answers, then please share your suggestion in code. big thx again.

example as follows:

[image]

```css
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color: #6B6B6B;
}
img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100vh;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
    #logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 110px;
    left: 10%;
    width: 123px;
    margin-left: -61.5px; /* half width */
}
</style>
```

```html
<div id="logo"><img src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/logo2.png"></div>
<img src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/vid.jpg" style="width:100%;">
```

Comment: Having your `logo` div *outside*  the `body` tag is invalid HTML...

Comment: Can you add expected result in question for more clarity.?

Comment: add expected result? need to position the main image 100px from top. need to get the logo align between image left and side! small css/html fixs to edit design and overall balance  etc.

Comment: rayees, some more clarity above at (enter image description here)

Answer (score 0):

How about like this:

(Updated to add a 3rd column and media queries)

```css
body {
    background-color: #6B6B6B;
    margin:0;
}

img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100vh;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#container {
    margin-top: 110px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
}

#inner {
    position: relative;
    background-color: green;
    display: inline-block;
}

#col1, #col2, #col3 {
  width: 100%;
}

#col1, #col3 {
  min-width: 123px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

/* column widths defined in CSS */
@media only screen and (min-width: 400px) {
  #inner {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  #col1, #col3 {
    width: 30%;
  }

  #col2 {
    width: 40%;
  }
}

/* column widths adjust to image size */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  #inner {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  #col1, #col3 {
      position: absolute;
      display:block;
      top:0;
      bottom: 0;
      width:calc(50vw - 50%);
  }

  #col1 {
      left: calc(50% - 50vw);
  }

  #col2 {
      width:auto;
  }

  #col3 {
      right: calc(50% - 50vw);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
   <div id="inner">
      <div id="col1">
         <img src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/logo2.png">
      </div>
      <div id="col2">
         <img src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/vid.jpg" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
      <div id="col3">
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: looks good sbgid. but instead to shorten and simplify the code can you use 3 .column (2 on each side and one for middle)!

Comment: That is simpler if the columns are all known widths, rather than adapting to the image scaling. I've updated the answer to include both methods at different sizes - you can use it to suit your needs from there.